# How do I format a code block in markdown?

Tags: javascript, web, formatting, markdown

I get a response from the server which is in a string format, I want to render it with the proper formatting for that language, and not be a single line code.

the response from the server

```markdown
`let response = "function hero(){ console.log("Hello, world!"); }"`
```

I want it to be rendered with formatting like this:

````markdown
```
function hero(){
    console.log("Hello, world!");
}
```
````

Comment: Take a look at [pretty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty).

Comment: seems like it only supports HTML

Comment: you could run it through pandoc with a custom [lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html)...

Answer (score -2):

You can simply solve this by doing:

```js
let response = '`function hero(){ console.log("Hello, world!"); }`';
    
// Remove leading and trailing quotes
response = response.slice(1, -1);
        
// Indent each line by 2 spaces
let formattedFunction = response.split("\n").map(line => "  " + line).join("\n");
        
console.log(formattedFunction);
```

Comment: It doesn't look like that input has any new lines.  What is splitting it by new line supposed to do?

Comment: it doesn't have a new line character